# Error when creating the firebase project using terraform

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a create a firebase project using terraform. I am new in it and need some guidance in setting up the firebase project. I am facing an issue

> Error creating Project: googleapi: Error 403: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the firebase.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

terraform code

```
resource "google_project" "test-project" {
  provider = google-beta

  project_id = "test-project"
  name       = "Test Project"
}

resource "google_firebase_project" "test-project" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = google_project.test-project.project_id
}

provider "google" {
  project = "test-project"
  region  = var.region
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the service account in the Terraform admin project, e. g.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create terraform \
  --display-name "Terraform admin account"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${TF_CREDS} \
  --iam-account terraform@${TF_ADMIN}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

and granting permissions to this service account should solve it. An example of providing permissions from the documentation:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${TF_ADMIN} \
  --member serviceAccount:terraform@${TF_ADMIN}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/viewer

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${TF_ADMIN} \
  --member serviceAccount:terraform@${TF_ADMIN}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/storage.admin
```

You can follow the instructions about [creating Google Cloud projects in Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform)

Projects you create in GCP are [the same](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#firebase-cloud-relationship) as you create in Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already had tried this solution and I am still getting the googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden. If you received a 403 error, make sure you have the `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` permission. I think the reason is, I am running on free trial account and the service account cannot create the project without specifying the parent which could be an organization and since the trial account cannot create an organization this could be and issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the firebase project but just a firestore database, then you can create a firestore database using the following trick.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/automate-database-create#create_a_database_with_terraform

> To provision a Cloud Firestore database with Terraform, use the google_app_engine_application resource. Set the database_type to CLOUD_FIRESTORE or CLOUD_DATASTORE_COMPATIBILITY.
>
> For example, the following Terraform configuration file creates a new
> project and provisions a Cloud Firestore database:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("credentials-file")
}

resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name = "My Project"
  project_id = "project-id"
}

resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = google_project.my_project.project_id
  location_id = "location"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```